# package.json file created in the wrong folder

Tags: npm, terminal, axios, serverless

I am creating an app to work with an API using serverless, and the initial install was ok. One of the folders that the `npm serverless install` does is `auth-server`, where two files - `handler.js` and `serverless.yml` are created (other than the `.gitignore`).

A few steps later, I had to install Axios as I will need to make a `POST` request for the API. Being on the auth-server directory, I ran the usual npm syntax to install Axios, `npm install axios`. To my surprise, however, npm has not created the `package.json` (and `package-lock.json`) file within the `auth-server` folder but used the root files.

I tried to look around to see if the problem was recurrent, but found nothing. I know that `package-json` file is created within the directory folder from where npm is executed as I have used axios a few times. Can someone point me where the problem may lie? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else needs this: I found out that although not in all cases, it is not uncommon that the npm will use the `package.json` file of the root folder. As I needed it inside the `auth-server` folder, I simply created another `package.json` file inside it (with a pair of curly brackets on it to avoid a parse error `code EJSONPARSE`) and saved it. Once I installed Axios one more (`npm install axios`) the `package.json` file began to be used and added Axios as a dependency.